# Can I build a watch app in Swift and add it to an iOS app that was not built in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch, watch

We built our iOS app in RubyMotion. We are just now building our first Watchkit app and would like to do so in Swift/XCode. The watch app that we plan to build is a companion to our iOS app, but it does not need to communicate with the parent iOS app at all.

Is it possible to add a Swift Watchkit app to an existing iOS app that was not built in Swift?

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is possible. Just enter an new target to your project and choose the language SWIFT to your Watch target:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Right, but the iOS app that we have isn't built in XCode. Is it possible to build a completely standalone watch app and then upload that to an existing iOS app in iTunes?

Comment: I don't think so. The watch App is embedded in the iOS App and installed by it. How have you built your iOS App?